# How to sort a space delimited file by specific column

Tags: python

I have a file contains data like this format:

```
1  2  3  [1, 2, 3]
4  7  8  [4, 5, 7]
```

Between the four columns, they are all double spaces(separated by two spaces).

How could I sort this file by the third column and then output it?

Comment: SO is not a coding service.  What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: I've tried some codes found on stack exchange but they don't work, so literally I have no idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep='  ',header=None)
```

Then sort by the third column

```
df.sort_values(2, inplace=True)
```

then save the file with the same format

```
df.to_csv(filename.csv, sep='  ')
```

Comment: what if it is just a txt file and I don't have name for the third column

Comment: I updated the code. You use header=None for no headers and it should be the column with the name 2 because the names will be 0, 1, 2...